# Dotlesscss @import statement: can't find file. Using Combres

Tags: asp.net-mvc, import, dotless, combres

In an asp.net mvc 3 project, i'm using [Combres](http://combres.codeplex.com/) to combine and minify my CSS files. I'm using the [dotlesscss](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) filter for fancy css extras such as variables.

However, when i try to use the [dotlesscss @import statement](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/wiki) (see importing at bottom of page), css generation failes with the following error:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\colors.less'.
```

It's clear that the dotless compiler is looking in the wrong directory, however: how to fix this?

[edit]: as requested: i tried the following synaxes:

```
@import "Colors.less"
@import "~/Content/Colors.less"
```

Comment: Could you post the less code in question that you are trying to compile?

Comment: Do you user absolute paths? Moving to relative could help. I use chirpy VS extension to compile and combine js/coffee and css/less files, you could give it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `DotlessCssCombineFilter` instead of the `DotlessCssFilter`. Then remove the `@import` statements from your *.less files, and instead import the *.less files in the right order inside the `resourceSet`.

Comment: Awesome! You the man!

Now to find out how to use Combres with a non-crippled dotless version. :)

Comment: @Epskampie I assume you refer to the fact that Combres works with dotless 1.2.0.0 instead of 1.2.2.0? In that case, just update your reference (not via NuGet) to 1.2.2.0, and rewrite an assembly binding as follows:

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="dotless.Core" publicKeyToken="96b446c9e63eae34" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.2.0" newVersion="1.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: Wow, that actually works! You just solved every problem i had with combres and dotless, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is a work around, not a fix.

Here is [the fix to the issue](http://pknopf.com/blog/using-less-correctly-with-combres) and here is the [suggestion to the Combres team](https://combres.codeplex.com/discussions/362265).

Comment: I know this is an old post, but the link to the fix is broken. Is there another location I can find the fix?